# Javascript: How can a popup close itself?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a page that sometimes open in a popup and sometimes open normally. How can I create a link that closes the page if it's in a popup?

Answer (score 8):

Use javascript:

```
window.close();
```

Or in a link:

```
<a href="javascript: window.close();">CLOSE ME</a>
```

Comment: Of course, this does also assumes the browser allows javascript to close windows/tabs. Not all do anymore, and in some cases the user has the option to disable it or not.

Comment: @eidylon -- well if you know of a better way without javascript let me know. the only other way I know is press the `X` in the top corner.

Comment: no, I don't, I wasn't criticizing your answer, more just pointing it out as a caveat for the OP. Letting them know ultimately this ability rests in the hand of the user.